# Is this a valid implementation of thread waiting/pulsing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

As the title says, is this a valid implementation? I'm aware of the `lock` statement's problems, but due to requirements it must be used. Is this code valid?

```
lock (richTextBox)
{
    Monitor.Wait(richTextBox);
    richTextBox.AppendText("Text");
    Monitor.PulseAll(richTextBox);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what "is this a valid implementation" means?  What problems do you suspect that are causing you to bring the code here?  For example, "does it *compile*" is one measure of valid code.  I'm sure it *does* compile.  But you could have used a compiler to figure that out.  As for if it correctly implements the algorithm, have you tried it out?  Did it work?  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I think people are being a little harsh with this question, there is a clear misunderstanding of how monitors work here, and it warrants correction. Please comment when you down-vote.

Comment: Thanks @MerlynMorgan-Graham for the cogent description of the weaknesses of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense because every thread will block on the `Monitor.Wait`, and none will ever be release unless some other block of code calls `Monitor.PulseAll`. Normally waits/pulses are used in producer/consumer type scenarios (i.e. one or more threads are waiting for another thread to accomplish some task or provide some data).

If you're question is more regarding the use of `lock` statement rather than: `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit`, that part is fine.

According to the MSDN article:

```
lock(obj) { ... }
```

should be the same as:

```
Monitor.Enter(obj); try { ... } finally { Monitor.Exit(obj); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - I just wanted clarification to see if I understood the concept of Monitor.Wait/Pulse. I see what you mean regarding the Wait method.

Comment: It's important to understand that when Monitor.Wait is called the lock is released, thus allowing other threads to enter the lock. When PulseAll is called all the threads that previously called wait will be released, but not simultaneously, since only one can re-obtain the lock at a time. When another thread calls Pulse/PulseAll the threads blocked on a Wait are moved to ready queue, but don't re-acquire the lock and proceed until the thread that did the pulsing releases the lock (either by exiting the block, or by calling Wait itself.

Comment: Between the wikipedia article on the concept of Monitors en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29 and the MSDN article on the Monitor class: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx you should be able to gain a fairly solid understanding of their function.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I'm understanding better now.